# printing paths from arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, function, math

I have a 2d array `a[3][3]` and the program reads 2 sets of IDs for 2 numbers on the array.
I need to print all the possible paths from one number to another.

So far, I know how to find how many paths exist every time:

```
scanf("%d %d",&ai,&aj);
scanf("%d %d",&bi,&bj);

distance_i = bi - ai;
if(distance_i<0){distance_i=distance_i*-1;}
distance_j = bj - aj;
if(distance_j<0){distance_j=ap_j*-1;}
path = 1+(distance_i*distance_j);
```

For example, if the array a is:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

With

```
input_1: 0,0
input_2: 1,2
```

The output must be:

```
there are 3 possible paths:
    a) 1,2,5,8
    b) 1,4,5,8
    c) 1,4,7,8
```

But I can't find a way to print them. Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain what “all the possible paths” means. Post how you “find how many routs exist every time”.

Comment: You may find helpful Lee's algorithm, even though not much related to your actual problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_algorithm

Comment: If you show the code you have to find the routes, someone may be able to tell you how to print them.

Comment: If you'd could come up with a title that describes a little bit more of your technical problem (and not your problem in life that results of it) you might perhaps see a way to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

From location[v1][h1] to location[v2][h2]

Move kinds are: `DOWN, RIGHT`

The width is: `(v2-v1) * DOWN`

The height is: `(h2-h2) * RIGHT`

=> all path choice action list: `[width, height] = [(v2-v1) * DOWN, (h2-h2) * RIGHT]`

**Example:** from location[0][0] to location [2][1]

action list `= [DOWN, DOWN, RIGHT]`

all unique path choices are (It make minus the duplicate repeated permutation from a given list):

[DOWN, DOWN, RIGHT]

[DOWN, RIGHT, DOWN]

[RIGHT, DOWN, DOWN]

Answer (score 0):

You will use backtracking (Depth-First Search) to **find all possible routes**.

See program test here http://ideone.com/GqWLa5

```
#define VALID(x) ((x) >= 0 && (x) < 3)

int arr[3][3];

// to detect previous visited cells and eliminate infinite recursion
short vis[3][3] = { 0 }; 

int xtar, ytar; // destination cell
int xsrc, ysrc; // source cell

// to move in directions: down, up, right, and left, respectively
const int dirx[] = { 0, 0, 1, -1 };
const int diry[] = { 1, -1, 0, 0 };

// temp buffer to print paths
// max size = size of arr + zero termination char
char tmp_path[3 * 3 + 1];

void rec(int x, int y, int idx) // idx is used to fill tmp_path
{
   int i;
   tmp_path[idx] = arr[y][x] + '0';
   if (x == xtar && y == ytar) // basic case
   {
      tmp_path[idx + 1] = 0; // put zero char
      printf("%s\n", tmp_path); // print path
      return;
   }
   if (vis[y][x]) return; // already visited
   vis[y][x] = 1; // otherwise, mark as visited
   for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) // for each of the 4 directions
      if (VALID(y + diry[i]) && VALID(x + dirx[i]))
         rec(x + dirx[i], y + diry[i], idx + 1);
   vis[y][x] = 0; // reset visited so that can be visited again
}

main()
{
   // input xtar, ytar, xsrc, ysrc, arr
   rec(xsrc, ysrc, 0);
}
```

Comment: well that seems to be it. but it's way more advanced than the things we learned so far in the school

Comment: Review the link in the answer. It prints all paths. I don't think there is a simpler method, unless you mean another thing by "all possible routes" which are not clear enough.

Comment: Then you need to take a look at the other answer. He gives you only the algorithm, and you have to write its C code.